# Django doesn't find template in templates/app directory

Tags: django, django-templates

In one of my project the template is being searched at

```
<project_root>/<app>/templates/
```

while in another it is being searched in

```
<project_root>/<app>/templates/<app>/
```

What exactly does this depend on

Both project's settings.py have the following exact same configuration in settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    }, ]
```

Here is the error

```
> TemplateDoesNotExist at /printer_add printer_add.html Request
> Method:   GET Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/printer_add Django
> Version:  3.0.3 Exception Type:   TemplateDoesNotExist Exception Value:   
> printer_add.html Exception
> Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py
> in select_template, line 47 Python Executable:    /usr/bin/python3 Python
> Version:  3.6.8 Python Path:   ['/opt/app/w_apps', 
> '/usr/lib64/python36.zip',  '/usr/lib64/python3.6', 
> '/usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload', 
> '/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages', 
> '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', 
> '/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages', 
> '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages',  '/opt/app/w_apps'] Server
> time: Fri, 13 Mar 2020 10:38:48 +0000 Template-loader postmortem
> Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
> 
> Using engine django:
> 
> django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/printer_add.html
> (Source does not exist)
> django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/printer_add.html
> (Source does not exist)
> django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
> /opt/app/w_apps/sts/templates/printer_add.html (Source does not exist)
```

Handling view is

```
class PrinterCreate(CreateView):
    model = Printer
    form_class = PrinterCreateForm
    template_name = 'printer_add.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('printer_list')
```

Comment: You haven't shown the views or error messages. I suspect that in one project, you have something like `return(request, "my_template.html")` and in the other you have `return render(request, "app/my_template.html")`. The advantage of using `app/my_template.html` is that multiple apps can have a template with the same name without clashing.

Comment: I just updated the error in the original question.

Comment: OK, so what is the view that is handling `/printer_add`? Where is the `printer_add.html` template?

Comment: It is in /opt/app/w_apps/sts/templates/sts/ folder. The view is updated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the template in `/opt/app/w_apps/sts/templates/sts/printer_add.html`

The traceback shows it is looking in the `/opt/app/w_apps/sts/templates` directory. This is because you have `'APP_DIRS': True` in your `TEMPLATES` setting.

If you split the template location into two you get:

```
/opt/app/w_apps/sts/templates/sts/printer_add.html = /opt/app/w_apps/sts/templates/ + sts/printer_add.html
```

Therefore you should use `sts/printer_add.html` as the template name in your view.

```
class PrinterCreate(CreateView):
    ...
    template_name = 'sts/printer_add.html'
```